# Check that 3rd party applications are installed before running and exit gracefully if they are not

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have an app and although I disagree with it, I have to add a check when the app is first fired to validate that the required assemblies are installed, and if they are not I need to exit gracefully with a messagebox. I have the code that checks this, and it works fine when validating that those assemblies exist, but when they are not present the app crashes before my code is run. Where can I put this check so it works?

protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {

```
        bool runningDotNet45OrNewer = CheckForInstalledDependencies.IsNet45OrNewer();
        bool slimDxInstalled = CheckForInstalledDependencies.IsSlimDxInstalled();
       .... If both are true continue with startup 
       .... If either are false show message and call System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();

        }
```

Comment: You can load the assemblies dynamically and deal with failures to locate the DLLs. Look at the load methods [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Reflection.Assembly_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). There is likely to be some pain in connecting the pieces on-the-fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application depends on those assemblies, you can't have it start and then check. It's simply not possible.

What you'll need to do is create a "launcher" application that has no dependencies. That launcher simply checks for the dependencies and either launches the real application if they're found and alerts the user if they are not.

Comment: I believe I am in a catch 22. To check for the existence of SlimDX.dll I just simply try to initialize it inside of a try catch. But in order to do that I have to it referenced when developing it and when I do the check in the launcher app it would have to have a reference to the dll to compile.

Comment: @scottlafoy - Then you need a better way of checking for the existence of the DLL.

Comment: I created a new launcher application in my solution and it has no references to the main application but it still crashes on startup before the check is done.